# What happens to files that aren't included in later unlocked packaged versions?

Tags: salesforcedx

1. Let's say I have a package called 'Meetings'.
2. Let's say I have 1 version of 'Meetings' that consists of 3 classes

   - A, B, C.
3. I install this package version in a Production environment.
4. Then let's say that later that day, I have a new package version of
       'Meetings' that only consists of classes A and B that I install in the Production environment.

**Question:** What happens to class C? Does it get automatically deleted? Or does it remain in org but automatically is unlinked with the package?

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm), I don't see this question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata components that are not included in the new version are removed from the target environment if they do not have dependencies. If there are dependencies on those components, Salesforce marks them deprecated instead of deleting them.

> Metadata that was removed in the new package version is also removed from the target org as part of the upgrade. Removed metadata is metadata not included in the current package version install, but present in the previous package version installed in the target org. If metadata is removed before the upgrade occurs, the upgrade proceeds normally. **Some examples where metadata is deprecated and not deleted are**:
>
> - User-entered data in custom objects and fields are deprecated and not deleted. Admins can export such data if necessary.
> - An object such as an Apex class is deprecated and not deleted if it is referenced in a Lightning component that is part of the package.

[Documentation Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_upgrade.htm?search_text=deprecate)